# What are the recommended parameters for OpenCV cascade training

Tags: opencv

I am trying to train a gender classifier but opencv_traincascade stops at stage 5. I need it to go to at least stage 15. I am using a good quality data set of 1,000 positive images and 600 negative images. My images are 32x32 pixels. My parameters are:

```
-numStages 20
-precalcValBufSize 2048
-precalcIdxBufSize 2048
-featureType HAAR
-minHitRate 0.995
-maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5
-w 32
-h 32
-mode ALL
```

What are your recommended cascade training parameters?

Comment: if you use a database available for public please add its link

Comment: what's the final message on stage 5? How many samples do you use? I don't think openCV cascadeClassifier training is good for your task, since afaik it is better designed for "detection by classification" than for real classification and strictly you have 3 classes: male, female, notHumanAtAll.

Comment: @sturkmen I have collected faces from various sources including Google image search. I wrote a cropping app to get very consistent crops of the faces with the eyes always at the same height in the images.

Comment: @Micka It exists with this message "Required leaf false alarm rate achieved. Branch training terminated.". The last FA was 0 so even if I lower maxFalseAlarmRate it's still going to exit there. I'm using 1,000 men for positive and 600 women for negative.

Comment: get more negative samples that fail with your currently trained classifier.

Comment: why did you need to do that. what is the problem with existing classifiers

Comment: Ok, it seems haar cascade training isn't the recommended way. Seems SVM (support vector machines) is the better way.